# Why is laravel renaming file Uploads?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a file upload system in laravel. I have a form for uploading images, and it works. The file gets uploaded to the server. However, the files are being renamed from their original name to something else. For example, a file entitled image.jpg will be renamed to phpgeaSOX, and phpgeaSOX will be saved on the server as a document. This is a problem, because in my image tags, I reference the uploaded files in my src to display them, and they will not be displayed if they have a different name.

Here is where I post my uploaded files to the server:

```
public function postUpload(){

Input::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/uploads');

    $doc = new Doc();
    $doc->title = Input::get('title');
    $doc->caption = Input::get('caption');
    $doc->path = 'uploads/' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

    $doc->save();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: usually done to make sure the file names are unique

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the file name as the 2nd argument to `move()`

```
public function postUpload(){

    Input::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/uploads',
      Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName());

    $doc = new Doc();
    $doc->title = Input::get('title');
    $doc->caption = Input::get('caption');
    $doc->path = 'uploads/' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

    $doc->save();
}
```